# how does $let access variables defined outside its expression in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

From the reference 
[$let (aggregation)](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/#exp._S_let)

we cat use `$let` to access variables defined outside its expression:

```
{
  $let:
    {
      vars: { low: 1, high: "$$low" },
      in: { $gt: [ "$$low", "$$high" ] }
    }
}
```

*In the vars assignment block, "$$low" refers to the value of an externally defined variable `low` and not the variable defined in the same vars block. If `low` is not defined outside this $let expression block, the expression is invalid.*

My question: how to define the variable `low` externally? use `var` or other choice?

Comment: What is `fenFactor` supposed to be? A field in the document? If so then why define a variable with `$let`. Is it just an externaly declared variable in code?

Comment: @BlakesSeven It's an externally declared variable in code. I want to know how to access the variable in `$let`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is only limited ways to create a aggregation variable in MongoDB as of Now.Apart form system variables users can only create variables in  $let, $redact, $map  operations.
(See Manual : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/)

Now Answer for your question is, you can refer variables defined in a $map or $redact  within a $let, that is what they meant in MongoDB manual.

Here I'm giving an example of using $map variable in $let :

```
 > db.grades.find()
  { "_id" : 3, "quizzes" : [ 3, 8, 9 ] }
  { "_id" : 1, "quizzes" : [ 5, 6, 7 ] }

//Using a simple $map:
db.grades.aggregate([{
  $project: {
    adjustedGrades: {
      $map: {
        input: "$quizzes",
        as: "grade",
        in: { $add: [ "$$grade", 2 ] }
      }
    }
  }
}]);

//Result:
{ "_id" : 3, "adjustedGrades" : [ 5, 10, 11 ] }
{ "_id" : 1, "adjustedGrades" : [ 7, 8, 9 ] }
```

Now defining a $let to use variable $$grade defined in this $map:

```
db.grades.aggregate([{
  $project: {
    adjustedGrades: {
      $map: {
        input: "$quizzes",
        as: "grade",
        in: {
          $let: {
            vars: { varin: "$$grade" },
            in: { $add: [ "$$varin", 4 ] }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}]);

//Result:
{ "_id" : 3, "adjustedGrades" : [ 7, 12, 13 ] }
{ "_id" : 1, "adjustedGrades" : [ 9, 10, 11 ] }
```

Answer (score 4):

I missed your declared variable at the top originally. You don't need to do anything, the actual value will be "interpolated" into the aggregation pipeline document "before" it is sent to the server:

```js
var fenFactor = 100;
db.sales.aggregate( [
   {
      $project: {
         finalTotal: {
            $let: {
               vars: {
                  total: { $add: [ '$price', '$tax' ] },
                  discounted: { $cond: { if: '$applyDiscount', then: 0.9, else: 1 } }
               },
               in: { $multiply: [ "$$total", "$$discounted", fenFactor ] }
            }
         }
      }
   }
] );
```

So just use the variable directly and it will become part of the document as sent.

You might also consider that [`$let`](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) is a bit terse here where you do not need to re-use the variables. Perhaps just do it inline instead:

```js
    var fenFactor = 100;

    db.sales.aggregate([
       { "$project": {
         "finalTotal": {
            "$multiply": [
                { "$add": [ "$price", "$tax" ] },
                { "$cond": [ "$applyDiscount", 0.9, 1 ]},
                fenFactor
            ]
         }
      }}
    ]);
```

Comment: is it possible to change the value of fenFactor from inside the aggregate?